# VBA Textbox remove last letter

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a program which converts decimal to binary and backwards while you're typing in the textbox. To do this, I have a check whenever the textbox changes to determine if the last character was a number (Using the Mid() function.)

My question is, instead of making the program send and error message when the last character is for example a letter, if there is a way to remove the last character from the string.

This is what I use to determine if the last character was a number:

```
LastChar = Mid(TextBox1.Text, Len(TextBox1.Text), 1)
If IsNumeric(LastChar) Then
     'Do the convert stuff here
Else
     TextBox2.Text = "ERROR: You must fill in a decimal number"
End If
```

I have browsed a lot on the internet, but all the methods I found did not work in the VBA I have to use for school. (Such as Me!TextBox1.Undo)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `TextBox2.Text = Left(TextBox2.Text,Len(TextBox2.Text)-1)` ?

Comment: I changed my answer: correct event is beforeUpdate. I don't remember if other events have the cancel parameter, too

Answer (score 0):

You can put your check code in the beforeUpdate event. If your test is not passed , you can simply do:

```
Cancel = true
```

So, put this in your else statement.

As suggested, you also need to call

```
Textbox1.Undo
```

Comment: You also have to call `Undo` or the text will get stuck.